Kafka in Docker retaining topics even with no external volume mounts
I am running Kafka in Docker in a docker compose with NO volume mounts except for /var/run/docker.sock. When I shut down the stack, the containers are destroyed.  I also prune the container volumes for safety: I want a clean Kafka when new containers are spun up.
But I am finding that when the containers start, Kafka re-creates the old topics from the prior execution, and further recreates them with only 1 partition (the topic had been configured with 4 partitions).  It also recreates the _consumer_offsets as well.
I've tried setting KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: false, but that seems to have no effect. There seems to be some persistent store OUTSIDE the container that Kafka is accessing, but I can't for the life of me find it.
I am not using Kafka Streams (there was an old post about that one, doesn't seem to apply here). I've looked for some rogue zookeeper files as well with no luck.
I found related log messages in Kafka startup:
...
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,021] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,095] INFO [broker-1001-to-controller-send-thread]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker kafka:9093 (id: 1001 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,234] INFO Creating topic my-topic with configuration {} and initial partition assignment HashMap(0 -> ArrayBuffer(1001)) (kafka.zk.AdminZkClient)
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,274] INFO Creating topic __consumer_offsets with configuration {compression.type=producer, cleanup.policy=compact, segment.bytes=104857600} and initial partition assignment HashMap(0 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 1 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 2 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 3 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 4 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 5 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 6 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 7 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 8 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 9 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 10 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 11 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 12 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 13 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 14 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 15 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 16 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 17 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 18 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 19 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 20 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 21 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 22 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 23 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 24 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 25 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 26 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 27 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 28 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 29 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 30 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 31 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 32 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 33 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 34 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 35 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 36 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 37 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 38 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 39 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 40 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 41 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 42 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 43 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 44 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 45 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 46 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 47 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 48 -> ArrayBuffer(1001), 49 -> ArrayBuffer(1001)) (kafka.zk.AdminZkClient)
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,303] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 1001] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(my-topic-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,353] INFO [Log partition=my-topic-0, dir=/kafka/kafka-logs-5d423ab1a90a] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,357] INFO Created log for partition my-topic-0 in /kafka/kafka-logs-5d423ab1a90a/my-topic-0 with properties {} (kafka.log.LogManager)
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,358] INFO [Partition my-topic-0 broker=1001] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition my-topic-0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
2024-05-17 08:57:37 [2024-05-17 12:57:37,358] INFO [Partition my-topic-0 broker=1001] Log loaded for partition my-topic-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)  
...

And zookeeper:
...
2024-05-17 08:57:37 2024-05-17 12:57:37,236 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100095707690000 type:setData cxid:0x45 zxid:0x20 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics/my-topic Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config/topics/my-topic
2024-05-17 08:57:37 2024-05-17 12:57:37,275 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100095707690000 type:setData cxid:0x4f zxid:0x26 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics/__consumer_offsets Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config/topics/__consumer_offsets
...

ANY guidance on where this data is may be coming from and how to stop it would be appreciated.
Here is my docker compose:
version: "3.8"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    expose:
      - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CFG_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: true
      KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: false

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock


Is there a producer running to create those topics? KAFKA_CFG_* variables are not valid configuration for the wurstmeister container, only bitnami/kafka, so the auto creation is still enabled... what happens if you try a different docker image? That one you're using has not been updated in 2+  years, and Kafka no longer requires Zookeeper

There's definitely no producer running (I rebooted the laptop to make sure there were no rogues processes running).  I will try the bitnami image again - I tried it before and had a bit of trouble connecting to it from outside the container.  Seems some of the setup is a bit different than I remember with the removal of zookeeper.
